# Framework path not found in one of Xcode scheme

Tags: ios, xcode

I have one of my own iOS framework embeded in my iOS application. I have workspace file where both framework and my application project exist. 
I have created universal scheme in framework project which takes care of updating framework changes in my application project.

I am able to run my application project with my default scheme. (say "ProjectName")

However when I am trying to run my project with other scheme (say "ProjectName-Dev), Xcode is not able to build project and gives the error:

> `"No such module <Framework name>"`

Any idea why one scheme is working fine while other not?

Comment: there are screenshots ?

Comment: I can try to explain it here with more details...which particular screenshot you looking for?

Comment: those two schemes has same target?

Comment: Yes, both of them have same iOS mobile app as target. (Schemes I have for dev and stage environments)

Answer (score 4):

Ok I found the answer to my problem. 
All I needed was to update my build products path.
I update my other scheme (stage environment scheme) build product path to same as my default debug scheme. 
$(PROJECT_TEMP_DIR)/Debug$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)

Where "Debug" is my default scheme.

Comment: Where exactly that "build product path" can be set?